# SharePoint 2013 REST endpoint URI structure. How to get list with localized title?

Tags: list, visual-studio, sharepoint-rest-api, localization, getlist

I can not understand how to work with localized lists. Using the article from msdn, everything works fine if my list has a title in English. But if I want to localize the sheet, I can not take the sheet either by Russian header or by English.

My uri :
"http://mysite/_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('myList')/Items?$select=ID,Title"
Works great, if list title not localized

Maybe I incorrectly localize the title. This is how I do it:

[image: This is my list in visual studio]

I created resources for the list:
English - TypesOfCertificates.resx,
Russian - TypesOfCertificates.ru-RU.resx

Next, I'm opening TypesOfCertificates/TypesOfCertificatesInstance/Elements.xml from the pic above and localized title and description.

```
  <ListInstance Title="$Resources:TypesOfCertificates,Title"
            OnQuickLaunch="TRUE"
            TemplateType="10501"
            Url="Lists/TypesOfCertificates"
            Description="$Resources:TypesOfCertificates,Description">
```

Next is TypesOfCertificates Elements.xml

```
    <ListTemplate
    Name="TypesOfCertificates"
    Type="10501"
    BaseType="0"
    OnQuickLaunch="FALSE"
    SecurityBits="11"
    Sequence="410"
    DisplayName="$Resources:TypesOfCertificates,Title"
    Description="$Resources:TypesOfCertificates,Description"
    Image="/_layouts/15/images/itgen.png"/>
```

And last is TypesOfCertificates Schema.xml

```
<List xmlns:ows="Microsoft SharePoint" Title="TypesOfCertificates" FolderCreation="FALSE" Direction="$Resources:Direction;" Url="Lists/TypesOfCertificates" BaseType="0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/">
```

List, like on this pictures, had right russian title. But how can I get it by andpoint api?

I hope someone can help to understand how to localize correctly. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get informations for all lists (inclusive localized title) by calling:

> http://mysite/_api/web/lists

You can get the same informations for a specific list if you call:

> http://mysite/_api/web/getList(@path)?@path='/sites/mysite/lists/myList'